# Detours Hook FindNextFileW Hang

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, detours

When hooking `FindNextFileW` with Detours I can not modify the returned entry without the process hanging. I am attempting to create a shim that exposes an archive as a folder on the filesystem.

The same thing happens when I set `LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW->dwFileAttributes` to `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` or use a logical or operation. The file's attributes are normally `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE` when the hook gets called with the archive.

Here is the code that I am using for this, error handling and logging removed for brevity.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <detours.h>

#define true TRUE
#define false FALSE
#define null NULL

static BOOL endsWithWide(WCHAR* text, WCHAR* key) {
    BOOL endsWith = true;
    size_t size = wcslen(text);
    size_t keySize = wcslen(key);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (text[size - i - 1] != key[keySize - i - 1]) {
            endsWith = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return endsWith;
}

static BOOL(WINAPI* realFindNextFileW)(
    _In_ HANDLE hFindFile,
    _Out_ LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW lpFindFileData
    ) = FindNextFileW;
static BOOL WINAPI ourFindNextFileW(
    _In_ HANDLE hFindFile,
    _Out_ LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW lpFindFileData
) {
    BOOL result = realFindNextFileW(
        hFindFile,
        lpFindFileData
    );

    if (result) {
        if (endsWithWide(lpFindFileData->cFileName, (WCHAR*)L".zip")) {
            lpFindFileData->dwFileAttributes |= FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;
            lpFindFileData->nFileSizeHigh = 0;
            lpFindFileData->nFileSizeLow = 0;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

BOOL WINAPI /*APIENTRY*/ DllMain(
    HMODULE module,
    DWORD  reason,
    LPVOID reserved
){
    if (DetourIsHelperProcess()) {
        return true;
    }

    if (reason  == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {
        DetourRestoreAfterWith();

        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)realFindNextFileW, ourFindNextFileW);

        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }
    else if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH) {
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)realFindNextFileW, ourFindNextFileW);

        DetourTransactionCommit();
    }

    return true;
}
```

I am sure that the hooks are getting called, as I can dump info to my log file when I have that enabled.

Comment: `endsWithWide` should check the length of the filename, otherwise you risk undefined behavior. But otherwise, have you looked with a debugger to see where it's hanging?

Comment: That is not the issue, as I can print to the log after that call. It is hanging after it leaves my hook and the target process resumes. I do not have access to it's sources or anything like that.

Comment: I didn’t say it’s the issue. It is however an issue.

Comment: Oh, I didn't release I didn't update the for loop from when I pulled it out and made it into a function. At least the second param will always be .zip.

Comment: I'm wondering if the reserved fields are somehow being used by the application/system when it is a directory. Maybe I need to calculate some values for that? Any idea what they might be?